# Tradução de "Falling in love isn't something one should do."

Tags: tradução-inglês, tradução

Traduzir isso como "***Apaixonar-se não é algo que se deva fazer.***" está correto? Por mais que eu traduza dessa forma, eu acho que de alguma forma está errado.

Comment: Pelo menos para a frase isolada, a tradução está ótima.

Comment: deve,não deva. Também existe enamorar-se. Tá certo mas sai mais formal em português do que em inglês.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A frase *Apaixonar-se não é algo que se deva fazer* também me deixa bastante desconfortável.

Repara que estas frases não têm problemas:

> Apaixonar-se não é algo que ele deva fazer.
>   Apaixonar-se não é algo que uma pessoa deva fazer.
>   Amar não é algo que se deva fazer.

Em todos estes casos, o sujeito do verbo à esquerda da cópula é correferente com o sujeito à direita, isto é, temos *[ele] apaixonar-se*, *[uma pessoa] apaixonar-se* e, com *amar*, uma referência genérica/arbitrária. O problema parece-me então ser a incompatibilidade entre o *se* nominativo, que marca um sujeito indeterminado, e o *se* inerente de apaixonar-se. Repara que também não podemos dizer:

> #Não deve apaixonar-se.  (no sentido de *uma pessoa não se deve apaixonar*).

com o *se* a valer quer por nominativo quer por inerente (tão-pouco podemos dizer *Não se deve apaixonar-se*, com dois *se*). Mas não há problema com *não se deve amar*.

Answer (score 2):

Other alternatives are:

- Apaixonar-se é algo que ninguém deveria fazer.
- Apaixonar-se não é algo que alguém devesse fazer.

Answer (score 2):

Há muitas formas de se dizer o mesmo em português, mas a frase soa melhor se o verbo "fazer" for omitido na tradução.

- **"As pessoas não deveriam se apaixonar".** ou **"Ninguém deveria se apaixonar."**

Comment: Mas isso não seria "people should not fall in love" e "no one should fall in love"? Perde a nuance intencional da frase original. É de propósito que o fazes? Trocas intencionalmente a nuance por clareza?

Comment: @ANeves    Eu não traduziria o verbo "do".  É como soa mais idiomático para mim em português.   Note bem que não há contexto para que se perceba a necessidade de dar um determinado tom ou outro.

Comment: @Andrej Hatzi   Caso o uso do pronome em próclise esteja errado, eu gostaria de saber o motivo.  Em pt-BR falado, esse tipo de construção é muito comum, mais até do que usando ênclise.  No entanto não lembro o que dita a gramática prescritiva a respeito.